# Haskell "Could not deduce..."

Tags: haskell

I'm a beginner to Haskell and was implementing some basic algebra, like

```
class (Eq g) => AbelianGroup g where
    gplus :: g -> g -> g
    gnegate :: g -> g 
    gzero :: g
    gminus :: g -> g -> g
    gminus a b = gplus a (gnegate b)
    gmult :: Integer -> g -> g

class (AbelianGroup d) => IntegralDomain d where
    idtimes :: d -> d -> d
    idone :: d            

{- you can ignore upper code, it is added only for sake of completeness -}

class (IntegralDomain d) => EuclideanDomain d where
    edeg :: d -> Integer
    edivision :: d -> d -> (d, d)
    egcd :: d -> d -> d
    egcd f g | g == gzero = f 
             | f == gzero = g
             | otherwise = let (q, r) = edivision f g in egcd g r

class (IntegralDomain f) => Field f where
    finvert :: f -> f
    fdivide :: f -> f -> f
    fdivide a b = idtimes a (finvert b)

instance (Field f, IntegralDomain f) => EuclideanDomain f where
    edeg x = 0
    edivision x y = (fdivide x y, gzero)
```

when I got the error

```
* Could not deduce (Field d) arising from a use of `edivision'
  from the context: EuclideanDomain d
  bound by the class declaration for `EuclideanDomain'
  at ...
  Possible fix:
  add (Field d) to the context of
  the class declaration for `EuclideanDomain'
* In the expression: edivision f g
  In a pattern binding: (q, r) = edivision f g
  In the expression: let (q, r) = edivision f g in egcd g r
```

where the error comes - as in error statement - from "edivision f g" in the dafault definiton of "egcd" in "EuclideanDomain". So as I am new to Haskell, my question is

> Why is there this error?

If I put (Field d) in the declaration of EuclideanDomain, this error vanishes. But then of course, the whole code becomes useless (not every Euclidean Domain is a Field etc.)

Comment: This code does not produce an error for me. Are you sure this is the exact code (maybe you used `fdivide` instead of `edivision`)?

Comment: I *can* reproduce the error on GHC 7.10.3, with several dubious `LANGUAGE` directives to get past the ambiguities.

Comment: By the way, just as a general note. GHC will sometimes say something to the effect of "error! ... you can use SomethingExtension to disable this check". Enabling the extension is usually a bad idea, so consider whether or not you actually need the behavior you're trying to get.

Comment: I cannot reproduce on any version of GHC (7.8-8.0.1) so I'm voting to close. (If any commenters are aware of how to reproduce precisely this error, please edit the question with the actual code necessary).

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I disagree with "enabling the extension is usually a bad idea." I often forget exactly an extension pragma that I need for something I'm doing, so it is very useful for me as a reminder. I guess it depends heavily on how much experience you have with the extensions involved, though. I mainly want to point out that extensions are definitely not a bad thing, in general.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Also, how are you getting the error? If I copy and paste the exact code in the question (after adding the two `LANGUAGE` pragmas GHC suggests), it compiles with no error for me on GHC 7.10.3 or GHC 8.0.2 (the only two I've tried so far).

Comment: @DavidYoung I suppose there are some extensions that are acceptable in general use, but haphazard use of `UndecidableInstances`, `OverlappingInstances`, and `IncoherentInstances` (all of which GHC suggests from time to time) leads only to more problems down the road.

Comment: @DavidYoung This is the exact file that I'm loading. https://pastebin.com/uSNZhVz7 It gives the error the OP reports. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. It errs in GHCI, with `runhaskell`, and also with straight compilation using `ghc` (with a trivial `main` added, of course)

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Ahh, I think I see what's happening. I missed the part of the question that says "If I put  `(Field d)` in the declaration of `EuclideanDomain` [...]". So I guess the literal code in the question does compile ok for everyone (if the appropriate extensions are enabled)?

Comment: The code, as posted in the OP's question and also on the pastebin that I linked, does not compile for me. Adding the `Field d` constraint does in fact fix the problem for me, but as the OP said, doing so defeats the purpose of the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152581/discussion-between-david-young-and-silvio-mayolo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** You probably don't want to do what you're trying to do. It creates too much complexity within the type system. The easy solution is to just not write an instance as generic as the one you're trying to write.

### The Long Version

```
instance (Field f, IntegralDomain f) => EuclideanDomain f where
```

You don't want to do this. I don't believe Haskell will even let you do this by default (you may have turned on some compiler extensions to get it to work at some point). What you're saying here is "every field is a Euclidean domain in the way that *I* say so". If someone comes along and makes a new type `Foo`, they may want to define an instance for `EuclideanDomain` and `Field`, but if they do then there are two instances of `EuclideanDomain` for the same type.

This is a problem. You can tell GHC to ignore this problem and just hope things work out with the `OverlappingInstances` compiler extension, but like I said, you probably don't want to do that, because it makes your code significantly more confusing. You'll probably also need `FlexibleInstances` and perhaps a few other ones to get a typeclass instance that generic to pass the typechecker. Now, you've got two options.

### Option 1

Just let sleeping dogs lie and assume the user is smart enough to implement both `Field` and `EuclideanDomain`. If you want to do this, you can make it easy for them by providing "default" functionality that they can just copy into their instance declaration if they truly want to derive `EuclideanDomain` from `Field`.

```
edegDefault :: Field f => f -> Integer
edegDefault x = 0
edivisionDefault :: Field f => f -> f -> (f, f)
edivisionDefault x y = (fdivide x y, gzero)
```

Then the user can implement `EuclideanDomain` of their own accord. If they want to implement the functionality themselves, they can do so freely, but if they don't, they can always do this.

```
instance EuclideanDomain f where
    edeg = edegDefault
    edivision = edivisionDefault
```

### Option 2

The other option, which you see from time to time, is more for the cases where the user might genuinely forget to implement `EuclideanDomain`. In this case, we would wrap our `Field` instance in a `newtype` and declare that `newtype` to be a `EuclideanDomain`.

```
newtype WrappedField f = WrappedField f

instance Field f => EuclideanDomain (WrappedField f) where
    ...
```

Then you still get the functionality without intruding on the user's instance space. This pattern is seen in the Haskell standard library. For the longest time, `Monad` was not a subclass of `Applicative` for historical reasons, even though mathematically it should have been. So, the Haskell language designers implemented a `WrappedMonad` newtype which took a `Monad` instance and provided the `Applicative` instance for it.

Comment: While this answer contains good advice, it doesn't actually (even attempt to) answer the question as stated (which is "here is some code, it throws this error, why does this error occur?").

Comment: BTW using [default signatures](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.2.1/docs/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#class-default-signatures) can make Option 1 even nicer: the user only needs to give an empty `instance EuclideanDomain MyType`.

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer, I'll consider one of these options for me. But as I'm new to Haskell, I would like to know what exactly is the cause of this error? Is it the possibility of making an instance to both Field and EuclideanDomain (and therefore the resulting ambiguity)? This error is still there, even if I enable OverlappingInstances!

Comment: @AndreiKh I'm honestly not sure. I'm able to reproduce your error but some other people are having trouble doing so (see the comments on the original question). With that in mind, I'm starting to lean toward the idea that this might be a GHC bug and that the correct behavior is to allow the code.

Comment: @luqui, that is nicer, but that extension is fundamentally upside down. You can only get a default definition of a superclass method from one of potentially many subclasses. For example, `fmap` could be defaulted based on `Applicative`, `Monad`, `Traversable`, `Comonad`, etc., and also some things that are not subclasses, like `Bifunctor`, `Profunctor`, and `Generic1`.